# Method running another method

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to run another method using `run()`?

```
public void a(int a)
{
    // Method1
}

public void b(int b)
{
    // Method2
}

//how to run code below
public void run(? b(23))  <--can be change to a or b 
{
    b(23);
}
```

Edit: What if I want to return a value from the methods?

```
public static int a(int a)
{
    // Method1
}

public static int b(int b)
{
    // Method2
}

//how to run code below
public static int run(? b(23))  <--can be change to a or b 
{
    b(23);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few ways you could do this. One way would be to define your `run` method like this:

```
public void run(Action action)
{
    action.Invoke();
}
```

Then execute one method or the other using:

```
run(() => a(3));

run(() => b(5));
```

---

If you want to return a value, you can either do so in two steps:

```
int r = 0;
run(() => r = b(3));
```

Or switch to a `Func<>`:

```
public T run<T>(Func<T> method)
{
    return method.Invoke();
}
```

And then call it likewise:

```
var r = run(() => b(3));
```

Comment: action.Invoke() is in void. how can I change it as string?

Comment: yes, I want it to return a value, I have change the code.

Comment: thanks Grant, its working now. just a little question. what does T resemble?

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about [delegates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288459%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)? You can achieve what you want like that with [Action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) delegate:

```
    private static void a(int arg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("a called: " + arg);
    }

    private static void b(int arg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("b called: "+arg);
    }

    public static void run(Action<int> action, int arg)
    {
        action(arg);
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        run(a, 1);
        run(b, 2);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: I'm hitting error where the action have invalid argument when trying to run the code run(a,1);

Answer (score 0):

```
public void run(Action<int> b)
{
    b(23)
}
run(a);
run(b);
```